# While installing Sitecore 9, the SOLR schema is not updated

Tags: solr, sitecore-client, sitecore-install-framework

When trying to install Sitecore 9, I am getting the following error :

[UpdateSolrSchema]:[Authenticating] http://habitat9.sc/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all
Install-SitecoreConfiguration : Error requesting http://habitat9.sc/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all: The operation has timed out.
At C:\SW\OneDrive_2018-07-02\sitecore9\SIFLess\SIFless-EZ-1531118582.ps1:67 char:1
+ Install-SitecoreConfiguration @sitecoreParams
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

We observed the siteore-XP0.json:

"UpdateSolrSchema": {
            // Update the solr schemas.
            "Type": "SitecoreUrl",
            "Params": {
                "SitecoreInstanceRoot": "[concat('http://', parameter('SiteName'))]",
                "SitecoreActionPath": "sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?indexes=all",
                "UserName": "admin",
                "Password": "[parameter('SitecoreAdminPassword')]"
            }

This script is executed but I don't know where we were missing some steps.

Comment: Are you using https? Can you access this url http://habitat9.sc/sitecore/admin/PopulateManagedSchema.aspx?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please follow the below steps and try:-

The correct procedure is:

1. Log in to Sitecore => go to Control Panel

   2. Click to "Populate Solr Managed Schema"
   3. Then click to "Deploy marketing definitions"
   4. Then click to "Indexing manager"
   5. And finally click to "Rebuild link databases"